# jQuery replace chars only if not

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

i would like to replace all the `"<" and ">" with "[" and "]"` but i want to not touch/replace all the `"<br>" or "</br>"`

```
$('.wysiwyg textarea').live('keyup',function(){

     wysiwyg_val = $(this).val();

    wysiwyg_val = wysiwyg_val
    .replace(/\n/g, "<br>")
    .replace(/\{code\}\{type="(.*)"\}/g, '<code><pre class="$1">')
    .replace(/\{img\}\{url="(.*)"\}/g, '<img src="$1"')
    .replace(/\{code\}/g,"<pre><code>")
    .replace(/\{\/code\}/g,"</code></pre>")
    .replace(/\{code}/g,"</code></pre>")
    .replace(/\{code\}\{(.*)}/g, '<code><pre class="$1">')
    .replace(/\{\/img\}/g,'/>');


    $('.wysiwyg-preview').html(wysiwyg_val);


  });
```

Comment: This scares me.  You're seriously going to run all those replacements with all those regexs on every keyup?  I'm not sure this is a good idea.

Comment: what you mean? how you think it should be? :)

Comment: i have to update a preview element for my little wysiwyg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier way to do this is probably to handle it in two steps.

Firstly,  replace all `<` and `>` with `[` and `]`.

Secondly, replace `[br]` and `[/br]` back with `<br>` and `</br>`.

Answer (score 1):

first replace `<br>` with fakebropen
then replace `</br>` with fakebrclose

`wysiwyg_val = wysiwyg_val.replace("<br>","fakebropen").replace("</br>","fakebrclose");`

//make your operations then

`wysiwyg_val = wysiwyg_val.replace("fakebropen","<br>").replace("fakebrclose","</br>");`